# name 'town' is not defined.Почему?И как исправить?

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot
import pyowm
from pyowm import OWM
owm=pyowm.OWM('68976fbbf786ee31d1f043d7aa628280',language='ru')
bot = telebot.TeleBot('823871901:AAFrwDCr2ettFfqpmHQZhyQtMcX5d-_lGh')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    town=message.text
    observation=owm.weather_at_place(town)
    w=observation.get_weather()
    a=w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,a)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Не похоже, что проблема в этом коде, приложите в вопрос полную трассу стека

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к переменной `town` вне функции `handle_text`, просто не показали это в примере. Так как переменная `town` определена в функции, то она существует только в ней и будет не определена в глобальной области видимости.

```py
def test():
    x = 20
    print(x) # 20

print(x) # x is not defined
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @КириллБлинов Если мой ответ правильный, отметьте его галочкой.